# python django error `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received

Tags: python, django-views

I am new to python, Django rest framework and I need help with a view

See the error I keep getting

```
    assert isinstance(response, HttpResponseBase), (
AssertionError: Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`
```

see my view

```
@api_view(('POST',))
def SeeAllMyModelCodeView(request):
    sender_ref = request.data.get('sender_ref_no')
    myModel = MyModelModel.objects.filter(sender_ref=sender_ref).first()
    serializer = SendMyModelSerializer(data=myModel)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Please advise me on how I can resolve this

Thanks

Comment: You need to `return` something if the `serializer.is_valid()` fails.

Comment: what If I want to return everything in the database

Comment: how do I return everything without passing through the serializer?

Comment: @MlikeEps: then you remove the `.first()` and work with `serializer = SendMyModelSerializer(myModel, many=True)`, and `return Response({'data': serializer.data})`

Comment: thanks pal, You are a genius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your serializer data is not valid, and you have no return value in that case.
Try this and see what is the problem with your data:

```py
@api_view(('POST',))
def SeeAllMyModelCodeView(request):
    sender_ref = request.data.get('sender_ref_no')
    myModel = MyModelModel.objects.filter(sender_ref=sender_ref).first()
    serializer = SendMyModelSerializer(data=myModel)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        return Response(serializer.data)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors)
```